Apexcharter dataLabels not displaying properly with add_line
While attempting to make a column/line graph with apexcharter, I noticed that the dataLabels reacted weirdly to the add_line function. Here is a reproducible exemple :
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(apexcharter)

dummy_data <- crossing(x = as.factor(1:6), group = c("A", "B", "C")) %>% 
                mutate(y = sample(1:20, 18))
dummy_total <- dummy_data %>% summarise(Total = sum(y), .by = x)

apex(data = dummy_data, type = "column", 
     mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) %>%
  # add_line(data = dummy_total, mapping = aes(x = x, y = Total)) %>%
  ax_dataLabels(enabled = TRUE)

If you run this code, it will display the following chart :

However, if you reactivate the add_line row, you get this result :

As you can see, the labels for group C are all stacked at the start of the chart. Weirdly enought if I filter the displayed data in order to show only two of the three bar-groups at a time, the labels will be correctly displayed.
Any idea what causes this issue and how to fix it ?

I thin it's a bug. When you add add_line, it changes the plot type (p1$x$ax_opts$chart$type) from "bar" to "line" and everything goes south from there. I don't think there's an easy fix for this (besides posting an issue to the repo and asking the maintainers). You can try plotly for a similarly looking plot.

Thank you for your answer. Yes plotly is very handy with its compatibility with ggplot. I'm trying to do the same with apexcharter as I used it for all the graphs of the Shiny app I'm developing, but like you pointed out it has its limit. I'll make an issue to the repo when I get the time for it o/
